# How to get the next available id in a certain range in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am attempting to figure out the easiest way to find the next available `id` in a particular range of ids, from a single MySQL table.

Assume the following id result set from a trivial query:

```
SELECT id FROM `foo`
```

Results in:

```
1
2
3
10
50
52
53
54
60
```

I want to find the first available `id` between the range of `50` to `59`. In this particular case, the answer would be `51`.

What is the best way to accomplish this with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Create another lookup table `bar` with enough id-values and use query:

```
select min(b.id) 
from bar b
 left join foo f on f.id=b.id 
where b.id between 50 and 59 and f.id is null;
```

If you cannot use another table, you can use a recursive CTE to mimic one:

```
with recursive bar (id) AS
(
  select 1
  union all
  select id + 1 from bar where id < 100
)
select min(b.id) 
from bar b
 left join foo f on f.id=b.id 
where b.id between 50 and 59 and f.id is null;
```

Comment: unfortunately another table isn't an option right now

Comment: But please be informed that recursive CTEs are only available since mysql 8.0 and after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the next free `id`, you can use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(id), 0) + 1
FROM `foo` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `foo` t2 WHERE t2.id = `foo`.id + 1);
```

If the `id` has a starting value (such as `50`):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(id), 0) + 1
FROM `foo` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `foo` t2 WHERE t2.id = `foo`.id + 1);
AND id > 50
```

If the `id` should be inside a range (such as between `50` and `59`):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(id), 0) + 1
FROM `foo` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `foo` t2 WHERE t2.id = `foo`.id + 1);
AND id > 50
AND id < 59
```

Note: `id` with `50` must exist, otherwise the queries above will not result in `51`.